# Which is the most imminent doomsday?

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, earth

By "doomsday" I define something which is caused by nature, given that the technological advancement of humanity stays the same as today, and also disregarding possible resource shortages.

For example, the sun will in 5 billion years enlarge enough to burn and possible consume Earth. I thought that was the closest.

But I just read this in wikipedia:

> Andromeda is the closest big galaxy to the Milky Way and is expected
>   to collide with the Milky Way around 4 billion years from now.

With this being stated, the exact question is:
**What is the most imminent known expected natural event which we would certainly not survive if it happened today?**

Comment: which question are you asking? which is the most imminent or will we survive?

Comment: There are a lot of events that we wouldn't really have any warning of, and, while extremely rare, can happen at any time, like being hit by a gamma ray burst, so this question is in general difficult to answer.

Comment: @Solar Mike & probably_someone: I am asking about the most imminent known expected event which we would certainly not survive if it happened today.

Comment: Then you should make that clear, because at the moment it is not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: As others have said, over the course of billions of years the notion of "we" (as in "humanity") is very much ill-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points worth considering:

1. Predictions for most “doomsday scenarios” have a probabilistic character, owing to our incomplete knowledge about the relevant details, and thus could not be considered *imminent*. For example, [predictions of asteroid impact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_prediction), a doomsday scenario that Stephen Hawking considered the biggest threat to the planet, are probabilistic even for known asteroids.
2. Collision of Milky Way with Andromeda galaxy is not much of a doomsday as far as the Earth is concerned. It is *extremely* unlikely that even outer planets' orbits in Solar system would be considerably disturbed by this process. This [section of Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision#Fate_of_the_Solar_System) provides more details and links to relevant papers.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about events which will happen in billions of years time, long after humans have become extinct. Any palaeontologist will tell you there's no possibility of humans still being here in a billion years time. You are asking about imminent threats, not things which will happen billions of years after we have gone. There is no way of knowing which of many possible scenarios is the one which will eventually finish us off, but I will mention a few which are much more imminent than the red giant phase of the sun.

1) All-out nuclear war. 2) A global pandemic similar to the i918 - 19 flu pandemic, but worse. 3) Climate change exacerbated by eruption of a supervolcano similar to the Deccan Traps, which erupted 65 million years ago. 4) Impact of a really huge asteroid, larger than Chicxulub, but no larger than some others which have struck the Earth in the last billion years. 5) Over-population and consequent insufficiency of resources.

There are no doubt other potential hazards, but that list will do for now. Regarding asteroid catastrophe, it is completely unpredictable except to say it will happen one day. That day could be in 10 years time or not for another billion years. It isn't unlikely that a combination of disasters will finish us off; probably a combination of the Deccan Traps super-eruption and the Chicxulub impact finished off the dinosaurs.

Comment: Point 2 aged interestingly